# Open source Task Management modules for OpenACS/TCL

Tags: tcl, task, openacs

We are about to build a standard task management (collaboration enabled) feature on top of our TCL/OpenACS based website and I would like to know if there are some open source modules we could leverage for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Project Open](http://www.project-open.com/) - it's based on OpenACS and is a perfect match for your requirements.